# how to use MySQL CAPI mysql_query with multiple sql statement

Tags: mysql

I'm in the phase of developing a C++ game-server project which interacts with mysql.

it said that lock table statement is cannot use in storge procedure so i workaround like this.

these sql statement is below

```
LOCK TABLE t_role WRITE, t_role AS t1 READ;
set @ret := 0;
call create_role(12, @ret);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

these sql statement did well in myql command  ,

but I write it with mysql capi it didn't work,

and, capi code is like this:

```
auto ret = mysql_query(get(), "LOCK TABLE `t_role` WRITE, `t_role` AS `t1` READ;SET @val_ret = 0;CALL create_role(12, @ret);UNLOCK TABLES;");
```

my c++ program print sql error below

```
sql : LOCK TABLE `t_role` WRITE, `t_role` AS `t1` READ;SET @val_ret = 0;CALL create_role(12, @ret);UNLOCK TABLES;
error info : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @val_ret = 0;CALL create_role(12, @ret);UNLOCK TABLES' at line 1, error code: 1064
```

my English is very poor, and I'm not so familiar with mysql, I don't how to fix this problem

it execute success when I just left one sql statement

```
auto ret = mysql_query(get(), "LOCK TABLE `t_role` WRITE, `t_role` AS `t1` READ");
```

but these sql statement I didn't desired.

once I add more a sql statement, it execute failed and error:1064

Comment: and it also didn't work like this below LOCK TABLE `t_role` WRITE, `t_role` AS `t1` READ;\ SET @val_ret = 0;\ CALL create_role(12, @ret);\ UNLOCK TABLES;"

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html
oh, by default both mysql_query and mysql_real_query are not support multiply sql statement,

just need to do this : mysql_real_connect(get(), dbip, dbuser, dbpwd, dbname, 3306, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS

the connect function last parameter